# Update a single nuget package on the command line (macOS)

Tags: macos, xamarin, nuget

As part of a CD build, I want to take a pre-release artifact published to a nuget feed and update it in our main project. However, I can't figure out how to update the package on the command line. The following commands generate the following errors:

Command

`nuget update $PROJECT -Id $PACKAGE_ID`

Error:

> MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.0' from
>   '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.18.1/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin'.
>   Unable to update. The project does not contain a packages.config file.

Command:

`dotnet add $PROJECT package $PACKAGE_ID`

Error:

> /Users/jeffward/Projects/(957,3): error MSB4019: The imported
>   project
>   "/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.700/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.CSharp.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk. Unable to create dependency
>   graph file for project ''. Cannot add package reference.

Is there any way to do this on the command line?

Comment: Do you have a try with Package Manager to update nuget ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/component-nuget?tabs=macos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error messages it looks like you are using PackageReferences.

For stable NuGet package versions you should be able to do this with a [PackageReference wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution#floating-wildcard-versions).

```
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="*" />
```

From the command line:

```
msbuild /r
```

Which should restore the latest Newtonsoft.Json version.

You may need to use 'msbuild /r /p:RestoreForce=true' if there is an existing obj/project.assets.json file to force the restore to re-run.

For pre-release versions you will need to include part of the version which indicates to NuGet that you want pre-releases.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.6.0-*" />
```

The above will restore the latest pre-release version, currently 4.6.0-preview6.19303.8.

Comment: Thanks! The change to PackageReference was I think what I was looking for short term, then updating using nuget restore worked.  Would still love a way that didn't require a change to the reference.

Comment: There are also some command line tools which work in a similar way to `nuget update` such as [NuKeeper](https://nukeeper.com/commands/update/) which might be worth a look.